# Path finding in JSON Code

Tags: android, json, google-api

I am creating an application which uses Google API got fetch details about google Books.

From the following JSON link I would like to retrieve data about the author and Title of the Book.

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android

My approach to the problem :

```
private Book extractFeatureFromJson(String bookJSON) {
    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJSON);
        JSONArray items = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

        // If there are results in the features array
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            JSONObject firstFeature = items.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeinfo=firstFeature.getJSONObject("volumeinfo");
            String title=volumeinfo.getString("title");
            JSONArray author= volumeinfo.getJSONArray("authors");

            for(int j=0;j<author.length();j++)
            {
                JSONObject authorFeature=author.getJSONObject(j);
            }

            // Create a new {@link Event} object
            return new Book(title,author);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

My approach towards path is wrong and I can't figure it out where is the mistake.

Comment: Can you put the JSON response?

Comment: Here it is sir https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android

Comment: `author.getJSONObject(j);` what makes you think the content of `authors` is objects?

Answer (score 0):

It retuns a book on first cycle iteration(1-10), u need to create a list of Books and return list.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Book` is receiving `String title, JSONArray authors` as parameters, is this right?

And I suggest you to create `List<Book> books` collection and add to this each book that the response contains

Answer (score 0):

Surely understanding how JSONs work is important and for this above answers should give you enough hints that let you handle this manually. My suggestion though is that you don't parse it manually and let automatic tools handle this for you.

You can parse it automatically with Gson to working classes.
Now how to tell Gson what to parse it to? There is a great tool called JsonSchema2Pojo that can handle this. Gradle plugin here: https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/tree/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin 
It is capable of generating classes understandable by Gson during build-time. I suggest using configuration provided in the repository and tweaking it for your needs.

The plugin interprets json schemas to generate the classes so you need to point directory with schemas in the plugin configuration. At first it may look like another complication but you can just generate the schemas using example answers like the one you pasted above using http://jsonschema.net/ webpage.

So to sum up. Using Gson and jsonschema2pojo you can make this task almost a no-brainer and focus on more important tasks (Except some situations when you need to write custom parsers). Configuration might take a while but still it's way faster than writing custom parser and you can easily change it just by changing the schemas. This comes in handy especially with external API you have no control of.